# Questions about Paul Krugman's 1998 Japan Analysis

Tags: macroeconomics, monetary-policy

I'm reading some of Paul Krugman's writing on Japan and the liquidity trap; specifically this article: [Japan's Trap](http://web.mit.edu/krugman/www/japtrap.html#Figure%201). However, I'm not an economist (just an enthusiast) so I have some basic questions.

First, PK uses the notation $y_t$ to refer to an endowment that's received at the start of each period. It's my understanding that this can be thought of as output, I.e. What individuals have to sell at the start of each period. Is it correct, then, to interpret the model as follows?

For $t=1$:

- The endowment is $Y_1$
- The nominal value of the endowment is $p_1Y_1$
- A portion of this is used to purchase one-period bonds and the remainder is used to purchase consumption, $c_1$. Cash is required for consumption but not for the purchase of bonds. Thus, $M_1 = p_1c_1$ is the money demand for period 1, where $M_1 < p_1Y_1$ if any bonds are purchased.

For $t=2$:

- An endowment of $Y_2$ is received
- The nominal value of the endowment is $p_2Y_2$
- Additionally, people will be paid from their bond purchases in the previous period, receiving $(p_1Y_1 - M_1)(1+i_1)$.
- Thus, total income available in period 2 is the nominal value of period 2 output plus the principal and interest on period 1 investment: $p_2Y_2 + (p_1Y_1 - M_1)(1+i_1)$
- This total income is then allocated to second-period bond purchases and consumption, $c_2$.

Essentially, my interpretation is that total income available in period 2 and beyond may be larger than the endowment received each period, $Y_t$, and this is due to investment. Thus, for any period t, if the amount of income that is used for bond purchases is $I_t$, then $C_t + I_t = RGDP_t > Y_t$ if bond purchases $I_t$ are above 0, the economy is closed, and the government contributes nothing beyond open-market operations and lump-sum transfers.

If the above is correct, then I don't understand PK's reasoning in section 1, where he makes some assumptions about periods 2 and beyond, saying that "from the second period onwards output (and therefore also consumption) will remain constant at a level y*." I don't understand this statement. I'm fine with the assumption that $y_t = y*$ for all $t > 1$, as PK says at the beginning of the paper that $Y_t$ is exogenous. What I don't get is why it follows that $c_t = y_t$.